# Multiple SQL statements passed together don't work as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, adodb

The following example code unexpectedly fails to return an error, when running two SQL statements through an adodb connection in VBA

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Set conn = return_connection(server:="Database")    
test_statement = "Select (1) if 1=1 THROW 50001, 'Error description', 1;"    
conn.Execute (test_statement)
```

However running the below statement instead

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Set conn = return_connection(server:="Database")   
test_statement1 = "Select (1)"
test_statement2 = "if 1=1 THROW 50001, 'Error description', 1"
conn.Execute (test_statement1)
conn.Execute (test_statement2)
```

Works perfectly fine.

Additionally if I copy and paste

```
Select (1) if 1=1 THROW 50001, 'Error description', 1;
```

into SQL manager it works exactly as I expected the problematic code to do: does a selection and then throws an error.

Can anyone explain this to me?

Clearly the obvious 'solution' is to separate out different statements to be run separately in VBA, which I'll do from now on.

However I apparently don't understand something fundamental about how Adodb works with SQL so I'd like to know what's causing this behaviour. Additionally I have non trivial multiple SQL statements that are concatenated and then passed into SQL through Adodb connections, so I'd like to know when that's safe to do and when I need to rebuild code.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `SET NOCOUNT ON;` as the first statement in the batch. This will suppress `DONE_IN_PROC` TDS messages (row counts) that confuse client code that is not expecting them. ADO classic is notorious for this (not an issue with ADO.NET).

Alternatively, you can use a RecordSet object and invoke the `NextResult` until all results are consumed.

Comment: I've just tested it. set nocount on didn't work for me in vb6 with mariadb.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your SQL statement carefully and it's a single statement and not multiple statement since there is no line separator `;`. Change your statement from

```
test_statement = "Select (1) if 1=1 THROW 50001, 'Error description', 1;"
```

To

```
test_statement = "Select (1); if 1=1 THROW 50001, 'Error description', 1;"
```

Moreover, if you want to execute multiple statement then consider wrapping all your SQL statement in a `Stored Procedure` instead

Comment: Unfortunately the ADODB sql code sill doesn't work as expected with the semi colon, as least on my end.

I am looking into stored procedures, and generally moving away from using VBA to store and trigger complex SQL- but unfortunately I'm constrained by other factors into using this for the moment

Answer (score 0):

I have had better luck using an `ADODB.Command`

```
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Set conn = return_connection(server:="Database")    

    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
    cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
    cmd.CommandText = "Select (1) if 1=1 THROW 50001, 'Error description', 1;"
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
    cmd.Prepared = True
    cmd.Execute()
```

**NOTE**: The `Execute` method of the `Command` object may return a `Recordset` object:

```
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = cmd.Execute()
```

I haven't tested the above code but it is based on code that is working.  I'm using Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects v2.0, but this should work with any ADODB version.  In my code I've wrapped my entire code block in a `BEGIN` ... `END` SQL block, and I've included semicolons at the end of each statement, although I'm pretty sure those are both unnecessary.

Edits to correct my mistakes and comments with suggestions or corrections are both encouraged.

Comment: I've just tested it. Didn't work for me in vb6 with mariadb.